# Input button remove "shadow"

Tags: css, button, input

I can't remove grey "shadow" effect from input type button on half of it:

[image]

I checked all methods on forum but:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
box-shadow: none;
outline: white;
```

doesn't work...

Excample:

```css
.background {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: white;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: white;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
<div class="box">
</div>
<input type="button" class="button" value="x">
</div>
```

Forum posting system force me to write something more because I have many codelines in post. But I don't know what can I write more? Everthing is on image and in code above. So I write what this forum doesn't like: "Thanks at all :-)"

Comment: you can't just remove the border? `border: none;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because of the border-style in the input type="button".

The reason you have that grey shadow is because it is set to 'outset', change this to solid for it to remove it :)

```
.button {
   background-color: black;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border-width: 2px;
   border-color: white;
   border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: yep! that's why it's good practice to just do `border: 2px style #color ` in this case style=solid

Comment: To expand on Cory's answer. If you still want the "press" effect, you'll need to add an active selector for it. e.g. `.button:active  { border-color: red; }`

Comment: I think somewhere in your code it is being overridden, I usually find the best way is to inspect the element and see what CSS is being applied to it. Wish you the best of luck with it though!

Answer (score 0):

change your`border-color` to `transparent` to remove any color, and will cause your border to take the color of the background due to `border-width` attribute

```
.button {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: transparent; /* NEW */
}
```

Comment: But I would like to white border, not black (like bacground). The problem is "grey" irregular shadow around rounded button. @Cory.Green solved problem in excample on forum but I have this solution in real code long time and it doesn't work...
Real code is too complicated to paste it on forum. So I am completly out of ideas...